# Enforcing Dirac delta-like Activations on a Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, loss-functions

I am working on a custom neural network model including convolutional and dense layers. I intend to enforce outputs a certain dense layer to approximate a Dirac delta function (or any localized pulse). The position of the peak of this pulse will be informative about properties of a sample. This enforcement will be based on an extra term on the loss function. My question is whether there is a nice way for adding this constraint. My initial idea was to apply a strong L1 penalty but this resulted a sparse but distributed (not localized) layer output which does not answer the purpose.

Comment: Could you give us more details? This may help with getting less vague answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of outputting a distribution, which you want to be as close to Dirac delta, just output a single scalar, which is going to be the position of Dirac delta, and then modify your loss function accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and sorry for the late reply! However, my problem is not regressing a scalar value which would be rather straight forward as you have suggested. My network attempts to approximate a well-known mathematical procedure and I want each layer to represent a part of the procedure. I achieve this by imposing several constraints to the loss function and one of those layers should have (approximately) delta response and with size N which is priorly known. As my question is not open enough, I will fix it and give more details. Thanks again.